# How to show a message if there are no results in the search

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I have the following problem in a Blazor application. When I access a page, I pass  parameters to a database search. This search may or may not return records. When the page is called, I check if the data already exists and if it doesn't, I display a spinner and then a table with the data. I'm not able to make the spinner disappear and display a message like "No records were found" when the search has no results.

This is the page:

```
   @page "/mypage/{param1}/{param2}"
   @attribute [StreamRendering(true)]
   @inject appContext myDb ;
   @inject NavigationManager Navegator;

   <PageTitle>Title</PageTitle>

   @if (myData.Any())
   {
   
   <h2 class="mb-4 text-center bg-success rounded-3 shadow-lg p-2 text-white">My Title</h2>

   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">

   </thead>

   <tbody>
   @foreach (var item in myData)
   {
   ...some code
   }
   </tbody>

   </table>

   </div>

   }
   else
   {
   @if (finishedProcessing == false )
   {

   <div class="text-center">
   <div class="spinner-grow" role="status">
   </div>
   </div>
   }

   if (finishedProcessing == true && !myData.Any())
   {
   <div>
   <h1>There's no data</h1>
   </div>
   }
   }
   @code {
   [Parameter]
   public string? param1 { get; set; }

   [Parameter]
   public string? param2 { get; set; }

   public bool finishedProcessing= false;
   public IEnumerable<Sncr> myData = Enumerable.Empty<Sncr>();

   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
   myData = await myDb.Sncrs.Where(x => x.Column1.StartsWith(@param1) && x.column2 == 
   param2).Take(20).ToListAsync();
   finishedProcessing = true
   }
   }
```

Comment: Hi, the `FetchData.razor` component inside the default template contains the validation `@if (forecasts == null)` to decide whether to show loading or the forecasts content, does this what you want?

Comment: Hi, the way I'm doing it works well to show the spinner or the data when it's loaded. The problem occurs when there is no data and in this case I need to hide the spinner and present a message to the user stating that there are no results in the search.

Comment: that means you will always get null so that it keeps working in `@if (forecasts == null)` and won't go into `else` so that the spinner is always existing? Then is it possible for you to replace `finishedProcessing = true` with other content such as give an empty/init value to `myData` so that it won't be null?

Answer (score 0):

In searches without results, a timeout occurred that caused the processing cycle to be interrupted. Treating the timeout and adjusting the cycle as below, it was ok.

```
@page "/mypage/{param1}/{param2}"
@attribute [StreamRendering(true)]
@inject appContext myDb ;
@inject NavigationManager Navegator;

<PageTitle>Title</PageTitle>

@if ((myData is not null) && finishedProcessing )
{
if(myData.any())  
{
...show data
}
else
{
<h1>There's no data message<h1> 
}
else 
{
Show spinner...
}
}
```